# EF - One to many??

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**EF:** 6.0
**.NET:** 4.5.2
VS2015

I must be not understanding something.  After research I can't seem to align this correctly.  Here's some abbreviated relevant code:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public ICollection<MailGroup> MailGroups { get; set; }
}

public class MailGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FromUserId {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromUserId")]
    public ApplicationUser FromUser { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Subscribers { get; set; }
}
```

With this code I end up with a one-to-many with tables like this:

### **AspNetUsers**

```
MailGroup_Id (FK)
```

### **MailGroup**

```
FromUser_Id (FK)
ApplicatoinUser_Id (FK)
```

This would seem to imply ApplicationUser can be part of one MailGroup since it is a single FK to the MailGroup, and I'm sure the meaning was to generate an ApplicationUser for each one, but is not the desired behavior.

The goal was to have a `FromUser` point to the right user, and to have multiple subscribers to that `MailGroup`.

Any guidance in laying this out correctly?

Comment: Hi do if I understand correct one Appuser can have multiple mailgroup and each mailGroup should have atleast one application user ?

Comment: Each ApplicationUser can have many MailGroups, a MailGroup can have **only** one FromUser.  Also, MailGroup can have multiple Subscriber ApplicationUsers.

Comment: hi is that possible to have mailgroup without any appuser ? in order words why we need one fromuser because it  will always be associated with some user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding  one Appuser can have multiple mailgroup and each mailGroup should have atleast one application user . here is my entity classes .Please have a look . Let me know if this is what you wanted or I misunderstood .

```
      public class ApplicationUser
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public ICollection<MailGroup> MailGroups { get; set; }
        }

        public class MailGroup
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public ApplicationUser FromUser { get; set; }
            public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Subscribers { get; set; }
        }
```

The only thing you need to do is to oveeride on model creating method to tell EF about this.

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(s => s.MailGroups).
            WithRequired(u => u.FromUser)   ;
    }
```

When I add a new migration after this the up method

```
       public override void Up()
            {
                CreateTable(
                    "dbo.ApplicationUsers",
                    c => new
                        {
                            ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                            MailGroup_Id = c.Int(),
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
                    .ForeignKey("dbo.MailGroups", t => t.MailGroup_Id)
                    .Index(t => t.MailGroup_Id);

                CreateTable(
                    "dbo.MailGroups",
                    c => new
                        {
                            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                            FromUser_ID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                    .ForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUsers", t => t.FromUser_ID, cascadeDelete: true)
                    .Index(t => t.FromUser_ID);

            }
```